# How can i update images in a pictureBox each time a file downloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebClient webClient;               // Our WebClient that will be doing the downloading for us
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();    // The stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the download speed
        int count = 0;
        PictureBoxBigSize pbbs;

        public Form1()
        {
            ...
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
                DownloadFile(ExtractImages.imagesUrls[count], @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg");
        }

        public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

                // The variable that will be holding the url address (making sure it starts with http://)
                Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("http://" + urlAddress);

                // Start the stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the download speed
                sw.Start();
                txtFileName.Text = count + ".jpg";
                try
                {
                    // Start downloading the file
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        // The event that will fire whenever the progress of the WebClient is changed
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
            Label2.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

            // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
            ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            // Show the percentage on our label.
            Label4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

            // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
            Label5.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
                (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
                (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
        }

        // The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Reset the stopwatch.
            sw.Reset();

            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg");
                pictureBox1.Update();
                count++;
                DownloadFile(ExtractImages.imagesUrls[count], @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg");
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 845, 615
            PictureBoxBigSize.pb.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
            pbbs = new PictureBoxBigSize();
            pbbs.Show();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbbs.Close();
        }
    }
```

In the completed event i added this two lines:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg");
pictureBox1.Update();
```

Sometimes it's updating the pictureBox and show the images right after each image is downloaded. So itl ooks like animation.

But sometimes in most cases it's not it's just show image each X seconds.
I tried to use pictureBox1.Refresh and Invalidate and now Update.
I tried to add also Thread.Sleep(40); or sleep(500) but so far it's not working on all the times.

I also created a new form so when i move the mouse inside the pictureBox1 area it will show the new form in bigger size with a pictureBox i want to show the images in the new form too. But same problem with the form1 pictureBox1. It's not loading the images fast enough. Sometimes it does.

The new form code:

```
    public partial class PictureBoxBigSize : Form
    {
        public static PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

        public PictureBoxBigSize()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox1.Image = pb.Image;
            pictureBox1.Update();
        }

        private void PictureBoxBigSize_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Way too much code IMHO

Comment: pb.Image is obviously nothing.  Get rid of that pb static variable, it's doing nothing for you.  Just access that existing PictureBox directly or create a method where you pass an image to it.

Comment: Make sure the asynch method properly invokes the update!

Comment: @TaW i tried to invoke the pictureBox1 in form1 in the completed event like this: if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg"); });  
                }  But it's never enter the if